# How to implement the repository pattern with updatable caches

Tags: design-patterns, repository, domain-driven-design

I'm struggling to apply the repository pattern in a project.

The requirement is not complicated:
1. When a client requests some entity list from a server, the client saves them to a local database for caching.
2. If there is a cache, the client should use them (within expire time).
3. When the client gets user action like refresh data or receives some notification, the client should update local data from a remote server whether they expired or not.

I learned the repository pattern abstract persistence of the domain entity.
So an application doesn't need to know where the entity comes from. 
(from a server or local database and so on.)

But how can I update local data hidden by repository?
By adding flags in the repository method argument?

```
fun get(id: EntityId, update: Boolean)
```

But I think that reveals implementation detail.
Should the repository listen to a domain event like `UpdateEntityRequested`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you answered your own question. You must somehow indicate to the client-side cache that it should update. That said, if you introduce that via events in your domain, then you are still tying your domain into a persistence concept.

The good news is that you can simply say, if there is an event at all for an aggregate, then you should update back to the server. It doesn't have to be a specific event. Any event in the stream is sufficient to identify that a change has happened.

Please provide more details if this answer is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I found that I made a mistake while applying architecture.
For my application, domain logic presents in a server.
So the repository was just a cache handler.
I decided to get an entity from the server and save it to the repository.